# How to redirect when user doesn't want to Authenticate on login page of IdentityServer3?

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

I am using **IdentityServer3** as an OpenId Provider. On the login page, we want to allow the user the return back to the application without Authenticating, if the user doesn't want to proceed. For example, use does not agree to the terms and conditions so we cannot log the user in or register. They are still anonymous users of the application that brought them to the IdentityServer. So it makes sense to have a "I dont agree, take me back to my app" kind of a link or button on the Identity Provider UI.

.NET has an OpenIdConnect middleware which provides an event handler called **OpenIdConnectOptions.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed** which should be invoked on the authentication failure.

First Question:
How to return a result from IdentityServer3 to trigger this OnAuthenticationFailed event handler in .NET Client? I haven't really found a way to returning an authentication failure. I don't know if a simple redirect without token would be good enough.

Second Question:
There are other clients (java, javascript, php). Since there is no .NET middleware on client side here, how can such response be properly handled by the client?

Comment: if you are using Idntiyserver3 why did you tag your question identityserver4?

Comment: When I initally posted this, the question was not just for IdentityServer3, but I figured IdentityServer4 Quickstart already has a cancel button that I can use, so I changed the question to make it more relevant to IdentityServer3 only

Answer (score 2):

OAuth 2.0 spec provides possible response types that you can use in the cases when user fails to get access - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1 (see section 4.2.2.1.  Error Response). So OP should redirect back to callback with URL parameters error and error_description. For example:

https://rp.com/callback?error=access_denied&error_description=User denied consent.

Answer (score 0):

Bychkov's response helped me figure out what to do on the IdentityServer3 side. Here is the code in case someone else needs it:

```
 //Get signinUrl from SignInMessage
 var queryString = new Uri(signInUrl).ParseQueryString();
               var signInId = queryString["signin"];
                var signInMessage = Request.GetOwinContext().Environment.GetSignInMessage(signInId);

                var clientId = signInMessage.ClientId;
                var client = await _clientStore.FindClientByIdAsync(clientId);                    

                var queryStringFromAuthorizeRequest = new Uri(signInMessage.ReturnUrl).ParseQueryString();
                var redirectUrlFromAuthorizeRequest = queryStringFromAuthorizeRequest["redirect_uri"];
                if (client.RedirectUris.Any(c => c == redirectUrlFromAuthorizeRequest))
                {                        
                    return Redirect(redirectUrlFromAuthorizeRequest + "?error=access_denied&error_description=user_denied_consent");
                }
```